# My variable is showing up as red when it's not indented

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and in my code I am attempting to get variables to create a drawing, although when I reset the variable c to false again it shows up red for some reason. For some reason putting a space in front of it changes it back but otherwise I am not too sure how to solve this as nothing seems inherently wrong.

```
from turtle import *
speed(100)

c = False
while c == False:
  n = int(input("How many sides? "))
  if n > 3 and n < 10 :
    c == True
    print("Correct integer input detected for number of sides")
    print()
  else:
    print("Only enter integers between 3 and 10")
    print()

#It's this one that shows up as incorrect 
c = False
while c == False:
  l =int(input("Enter side length between 20 & 80: "))
  if l > 20 and l < 80 :
    c == True
    print("Correct integer input detected for side length")
    print()
  else:
    print("Only enter integers between 20 and 80")
    print()
```

[image of issue on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1H23.png)

Comment: `==` is for comparison, not assignment.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see that. Thank you, the change has been made but the red mark is still there.

Comment: It looks to subtle to be an actual error; looks more like faulty syntax highlighting.

Comment: I see, i'll try to continue with it. Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**Your Code**

```
from turtle import *
speed(100)

c = False
while c == False:
  n = int(input("How many sides? "))
  if n > 3 and n < 10 :
    c == True
    print("Correct integer input detected for number of sides")
    print()
  else:
    print("Only enter integers between 3 and 10")
    print()

#It's this one that shows up as incorrect 
c = False
while c == False:
  l =int(input("Enter side length between 20 & 80: "))
  if l > 20 and l < 80 :
    c == True
    print("Correct integer input detected for side length")
    print()
  else:
    print("Only enter integers between 20 and 80")
    print()
```

Just Change
`c == True`
to
`c = True`

**Because**
`c == True`
returns True if c is equal to True

and

`c = True`

set's the variable to True

**If you have any queries Please Ask**

Comment: I am glad that that helped

Answer (score 0):

```
c == True
```

This is comparing if "c" is equal to True. It is not assigning True to "c". To do that you need

```
c = True
```

Comment: Don't you see the other answer: it is almost the same as yours but with more explanation

Comment: I had it opened on the browser and answered later. Didn’t see the other answers. Sorry for that.